# Should we strip JavaScript when allowing custom header and footer?

Tags: javascript, xss

Customers want to be able to provide their own html header/footer (for styling reasons), so that when they redirect to `customer123.ourservice.com`, the page looks like it's a part of their site.

Should we strip JavaScript in their HTML for security reasons? Can they do anything malicious (like if it's a public computer perhaps get session of another user)? I'm noticing that some other sites do not bother stripping JavaScript...

Comment: If they could do that with a public computer, so could your Javascript, so it wouldn't be a safe public computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they can customize header and footer it means they can add JS if they want/need. Let's say a tracker for example.

Generally XSS is a vulnerability if a malicious user can inject JS in the footer, not if your customer decide to.

In your case, they are using subdomain so yes a customer could set a cookie on your main domain

https://serverfault.com/questions/153409/can-subdomain-example-com-set-a-cookie-that-can-be-read-by-example-com

So depends if you have sensitive data in your cookies. If you don't there must not have any problems.

The flow would be :
A visitor land on the subdomain. They set a cookie for the main domain. They redirect or visitor by itself go to your main domain. You check value inside cookies and there it can be corrupted.
Every user can change its cookies but it won't be available for other users.

Another problem is that if they can set cookies, it can also impact other subdomains.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sylwit. What I was thinking of was more in the lines of -- if we have our product at `dashboard.ourservice.com` and their own page is hosted at `customer123.ourservice.com`, can you see any security issues here? Anything we should watch out for?

Comment: Edited my answer to be more explicit

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Makes more sense. The only thing we store in cookies is user session id (when they login). So, looks like if a user is logged in, and another malicious user asks a customer to visit their subdomain, they can intercept the session...

Comment: Yes that's risky. You as an admin can go on his website and give your session token.